# OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError with Rails4 on JRuby

Tags: heroku, openssl, jruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails4 uses an encrypted cookie session store by default. When the app tries to encrypt a cookie the following error is raised: `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: Illegal key size: possibly you need to install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for your JRE` (stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/8ba56b18060ae30e4d44).

As mentioned [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4326) this can be worked around by downgrading cryptography or installing JCE - the first being something I don't really want to do and the latter being impossible (afaik) on heroku.

Comment: Also running into this problem. Were you able to figure something out?

Comment: seeing this issue as well

Comment: @Mark There is an article on how to fix JCE on heroku now - see if this answer helps.

Comment: @GregoryOstermayr There is an article on how to fix JCE on heroku now - see if this answer helps.

Answer (score 18):

Not sure if it will work on Heroku, but [this resolves the issue](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/UnlimitedStrengthCrypto) on my local Jruby.

Create config/initializers/unlimited_strength_cryptography.rb:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java' # Allows the application to work with other Rubies if not JRuby
  require 'java'
  java_import 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

  begin
    security_class = java.lang.Class.for_name('javax.crypto.JceSecurity')
    restricted_field = security_class.get_declared_field('isRestricted')
    restricted_field.accessible = true
    restricted_field.set nil, false
  rescue ClassNotFoundException => e
    # Handle Mac Java, etc not having this configuration setting
    $stderr.print "Java told me: #{e}n"
  end
end
```

Comment: I got some ClassNotFound exceptions with Mac Java. To solve, wrap in begin/rescue/end like in this post: http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2007/05/24/dealing-with-java-exceptions-in-jruby/

Comment: Also, installation of JCE can be skipped if `gem 'jruby-openssl'` is included in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 3):

The Heroku Dev Center now has this article: ["Customizing the JDK"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/customizing-the-jdk).

> There are some cases where files need to be bundled with the JDK in order to expose functionality in the runtime JVM. For example, the inclusion of unlimited strength Java Cryptography Extensions (JCE) is often added to a JDK in order to utilize stronger cryptographic libraries. To handle such cases, Heroku will copy files designated by the app in a .jdk-overlay folder into the JDK’s directory structure.

Here's how to add JCE files to your app:

1. In your application’s root directory, create a `.jdk-overlay` folder
2. Copy the JCE `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` into `.jdk-overlay/jre/lib/security/`
3. Commit the files

   > $ git add .jdk-overlay
   >   $ git commit -m "Custom JCE files"
4. Deploy to Heroku

   > $ git push heroku master

Answer (score 1):

Using [Leons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476159/leons)' approach, this solved my issue in production, but broke dev without the rescue.

```
# config/initializers/unrestricted_crypto.rb
begin # Enable 'restricted' cipher libraries on crippled systems
  prop = Java::JavaxCrypto::JceSecurity.get_declared_field 'isRestricted'
  prop.accessible = true
  prop.set nil, false
rescue NameError
end
```

It's because different javas have different flavas... ...I'll let myself out.